# Can ASP.NET target .net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, bit-framework

I'm just added to a project which is targeting `netcoreapp3.1`.
I can see [bit framework](https://github.com/bitfoundation/bitframework) package is added to the project.
The problem is that this package(bit framework) seems to use asp.net (not asp.net core) 
On the other hand asp.net projects can't target .net core platform.
So how is it possible that a project which is targeting .net core, has dependencies to libraries that use asp.net classic?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The [Bit.Core](https://github.com/bitfoundation/bitframework/blob/master/src/Server/Bit.Core/Bit.Core.csproj) project targets

- .Net Framework 4.6.1
- .Net Core 3.1

as you can read in the project file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <Import Project="../Server.Build.props" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net461;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
    <PackageTags>$(PackageTags)</PackageTags>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="5.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target both net core app 3.1 & asp.net core 3.1 and net461+ with asp.net core 2.2
You can take a look at [this example](https://github.com/bitfoundation/bitframework/tree/master/Samples/ODataSamples).